# Can I get my breadcrumbs to display the h1 from the content page?

Tags: cms, breadcrumbs

Im adding breadcrumbs to cms content pages. I would like for the breadcrumbs to pull the h1 from those pages.

Comment: Im in Magento 1.9.  1.8 had a "Navigation label" field when creating a CMS page that went to the breadcrumbs.